# Applying Kapton Tape To Bed Plate

Tags: heated-bed, hbp

There must be a trick to doing a good job of applying Kapton tape on a printer bed plate…

We built a Bukobot and even with a great deal of care ended up with bubbles under the tape and occasional overlaps. I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a solution made for applying window tint, maybe even soapy water.  Squeegee it out, heat the bed for a bit and you should be good to go.

[This video demonstrates the process.](http://youtu.be/BEFFHMJXEFg)

Comment: Does the solution go between the tape and the bed plate?

Comment: I added a link to a video showing the process in my original answer.

Answer (score 2):

I like to heat my build plate up a bit before I begin. Just warm to touch. I feel that this will help prevent bubbling so soon. I would think that since the build plate is expanded with the heat, that when the tape is applied it will shrink with the build plate. I was also told that the heat would help the adhesive stick better.

The other thing I do when applying kapton tape is apply one end of the tape to a ruler, place the ruler on the far side of the build plate, and slowly begin working the tape evenly across the plate. I find it much easier to apply tape this way.